# RAILS_ENV=production is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

So I'm learning Rails on Windows 8 box from on online source. In the lesson below, I'm trying to change the Rails environment from development to production and precompile some files before uploading them to heroku.

When I run the below command:

```
PS C:\Users\username\work\stukdo> RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I get this:

```
RAILS_ENV=production : The term 'RAILS_ENV=production' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (RAILS_ENV=production:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have looked everywhere but cannot get this command to work. I've updated the PATH in my Windows box, but to no avail.

I have Rails ver. 4.1.8 and Ruby 1.9.3 running on the windows box. Any ideas?
Sorry if this is a novice question, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RAILS_ENV=production is used from Linux (or variant thereof) terminals to set an environment variable prior to calling some command.

To do this in Windows you will need to set the environment variable the Windows way.  This would look something like this.

```
set RAILS_ENV=production
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

---

**EDIT: Based on comment from TC**

Setting Heroku to use production is a different problem altogether.

Details are provided on Heroku's site at the following link.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments

The short version though you need to create a production remote and then push to that remote.

```
heroku create --remote production
git push production master
```

Comment: Is there anyway to check if it was changed to production. I ran the commands above, but when I upload the files to heroku, it is still using sqlite3. From my gemfile, it should be using postgresql. I think it didn't change the environment.

Comment: I've added some additional info related to setting this on Heroku.

Comment: @reodon59,  I rejected the proposed edits you made to the answer.  The type of edit you made would belong as an update to your original question if anywhere.  Based on what you had entered though; your original question has been solved.  The Stack Overflow process is that you should accept this answer and now go open a new question related to the separate postgres issue you are now encountering.

Comment: @bigtunacan...How do I do that?